# Sum of specific data in separate Excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in 2 separate sheets:
**Sheet1**:

```
    A   B   C   D
a   ff  dd  ff  ee
b   12  10  10  12
```

**Sheet2:**

```
    A   B   C   D
a   ge  ff  ff  ee
b   11  13  14  10
```

Now I want to write a formula to sum all the values in row 2 which contain `ff` directly above (i.e. in row 1)

In my example above I want to add (Cell Sheet1[A, b], Sheet1[C, b], Sheet2[B, b], Sheet2[C, b]) which is equal to 49.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For 2 sheets I'd go with brettdj's suggestion, but, generically, you can perform SUMIF across multiple sheets like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&sheetlist&"'!A1:D1"),"ff",INDIRECT("'"&sheetlist&"'!A2:D2")))`

where sheetlist is a named range containing all the sheet names

Comment: My suggestion was to use a named range but it could be any range reference, e.g. put the sheet names in G1:G10 and use that reference in place of sheetname. Alternatively you can name that range of cells by selecting the range, right-clicking and using "Name a range". Any blanks in that range would cause a problem so you might want to look at "dynamic named ranges" should you need to update the list.....

Answer (score 10):

This is a typical job for `SUMIF`. As `SUMIF` isn't natively a 3D function that works accross multiple sheets, you will need a formula such as this one (entered on Sheet1) combining the totals from both sheets

`=SUMIF(A1:D1,"ff",A2:D2)+SUMIF(Sheet2!A1:D1,"ff",Sheet2!A2:D2)`

*Note this question would have been better asked on Super User as it is not programming*