# How to outline the range of several columns and tabs in 3D formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

After a lot of searching I succeed making a formula with a reference to another tab (March) > `=SUMIF(maart!$Z7:$Z47,"410200",maart!$W7:$W47)` ... :)

Nevertheless I need some help ...

1) How to adjust the formula (as concise as possible) to search for multiple columns? So not only `$W7:$W47` but also `$X7:$X47` and `$Y7:$Y47` in the same month.

2) How to adjust the formula to search on multiple tabs? From januari!:december!

Thanks in advance!

[edit]
I know now how to put 2 (12) months into a formula:

```
=SUMIF(maart!$Z7:$Z47,"410200",maart!$W7:$W47)+SUMIF(april!$Z7:$Z47,"410200",april!$W7:$W47)
```

... but it is surely possible to shorten such a long string, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple sheets have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274033/sum-of-specific-data-in-separate-excel-sheets/11274528#11274528)

....but for multiple columns I think you would have  to repeat the formula (criteria and sum ranges are always the same size in `SUMIF`)

If you want to generate "sheetlist" automatically in the formula then for all 12 months you can use an expression like

`=TEXT({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}*29,"MMMM")`

You might have to change `"MMMM"` depending on your regional settings